# Group by multiple properties in a array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, grouping, reduce

Grouping an array by multiple properties, iam able to do grouping with single property but iam not getting correct output using 2 properties

I have an array like this

```
var grouping=
    [
     {
        name: "Micheal", 
        branch: "arts",
        school: "little star"
      },
      {
        name: "james", 
        branch: "science",
        school: "little flower"
      },
      {
        name: "Harry", 
        branch: "arts",
        school: "little star"
      },
      {
        name: "emma", 
        branch: "science",
        school: "little flower"
      },
      {
        name: "Schmitt,", 
        branch: "zoology",
        school: "Buds And Flowers High School"
      },
      {
        name: "Tobias,", 
        branch: "biology",
        school: "Boarding School"
      }
    ]
```

i want to group by (branch, school)
and the output should be

```
[
  [
    {
    name: "Micheal", 
    branch: "arts",
    school: "little star"
    },
   {
    name: "Harry", 
    branch: "arts",
    school: "little star"
   }
 ], 
  [
   {
    name: "james", 
    branch: "science",
    school: "little flower"
   },
   {
    name: "emma", 
    branch: "science",
    school: "little flowe"
   }
  ],
   {
    name: "Schmitt,", 
    branch: "zoology",
    school: "Buds And Flowers High School"
  },
  {
    name: "Tobias,", 
    branch: "biology",
    school: "Boarding School"
  }
]
```

iam able to do grouping successfully using single property(branch) below code
grouping= above array

```
var hash = Object.create(null),
        result = [];

      this.grouping.forEach(function (a) {
        if (!hash[a['branch']] ) {
          hash[a['branch']] = [];
          result.push(hash[a['branch']]);
        }
        hash[a['branch']].push(a);
      }); 
      console.log( result)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

thanks

Comment: do yoi habe another example where branch and school is not the same? btw, what have you tried and what does not work?

Comment: You mean need to satisfy 2 condition on grouping?

Comment: I think this will help you to solve your problem https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37028/grouping-elements-in-array-by-multiple-properties

Comment: @Tijo John  yes need to satify 2 conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate a combined key of the wanted groups and get the values from a collecting object.

```js
var data = [{ name: "Micheal",  branch: "arts", school: "great star" }, { name: "james",  branch: "science", school: "little flower" }, { name: "Harry",  branch: "arts", school: "little star"  }, { name: "emma",  branch: "science",  school: "little flower" }, { name: "Schmitt,", branch: "zoology", school: "Buds And Flowers High School" }, { name: "Tobias,",  branch: "biology", school: "Boarding School" }],
    groups = ['branch', 'school'],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
        const key = groups.map(k => o[k]).join('|');
        (r[key] ??= []).push(o);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Grouping by array index might not be ideal future proofing. I'd suggest grouping by key, and then you can simply extract the whole object(s) by referencing the key.

Like so

```js
let all_data = [{
    name: "Micheal",
    branch: "arts",
    school: "little star"
  },
  {
    name: "james",
    branch: "science",
    school: "little flower"
  },
  {
    name: "Harry",
    branch: "arts",
    school: "little star"
  },
  {
    name: "emma",
    branch: "science",
    school: "little flower"
  }
];

let items = groupBy(all_data, 'branch')
for (let branch in items)
  items[branch] = groupBy(items[branch], 'school')

console.log(JSON.stringify(items))

//{
//  "arts": {
//     "little star":[
//         { "name":"Micheal", "branch":"arts", "school":"little star" }, 
//         { "name":"Harry", "branch":"arts", "school":"little star" }
//      ]
//   },
//   "science": {
//      "little flower":[
//         { "name":"james", "branch":"science", "school":"little flower" }, 
//         { "name":"emma", "branch":"science", "school":"little flower"}
//      ]
//   }
//}

//group an array of objects into an object by object key
function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
  return objectArray.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    if (!acc[obj[property]])
      acc[obj[property]] = [];
    acc[obj[property]].push(obj);
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added `if` flag when the value has one. The value is found by filter function which find one value without same one. After value is found then solo value just pushed to result array.

```js
/*
[
  [
    {
    name: "Micheal", 
    branch: "arts",
    school: "little star"
    },
   {
    name: "Harry", 
    branch: "arts",
    school: "little star"
   }
 ], 
  [
   {
    name: "james", 
    branch: "science",
    school: "little flower"
   },
   {
    name: "emma", 
    branch: "science",
    school: "little flowe"
   }
  ],
   {
    name: "Schmitt,", 
    branch: "zoology",
    school: "Buds And Flowers High School"
  },
  {
    name: "Tobias,", 
    branch: "biology",
    school: "Boarding School"
  }
]
*/
var grouping=
    [
     {
        name: "Micheal", 
        branch: "arts",
        school: "little star"
      },
      {
        name: "james", 
        branch: "science",
        school: "little flower"
      },
      {
        name: "Harry", 
        branch: "arts",
        school: "little star"
      },
      {
        name: "emma", 
        branch: "science",
        school: "little flower"
      },
      {
        name: "Schmitt,", 
        branch: "zoology",
        school: "Buds And Flowers High School"
      },
      {
        name: "Tobias,", 
        branch: "biology",
        school: "Boarding School"
      }
    ]
    
var hash = Object.create(null),
        result = [];

      this.grouping.forEach(function (a) {      
      
      //this filter to find solo value.
      let solo = grouping.filter((one) => one.branch === a.branch).length;        
      let sortBySchool = grouping.filter((one) => one.school === a.school).length;
      //this filter to find a value which have 2 conditions.
      let sortBy2Condition = grouping.filter((one) => 
      one.school === a.school && one.branch === a.branch
      ).length;
      
      //if only value then just push to result arry.
        if (solo === 1) {                  
          result.push(a);
        } else {
        if (!hash[a['branch']] ) {
          hash[a['branch']] = [];
          result.push(hash[a['branch']]);
        }
        hash[a['branch']].push(a);
      }
      }); 
      
      console.log( result)
```